# Google OAuth 2.0 exchanging code form access token takes forver

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth

I have a basic web app that I uses Google OAUTH flow. The web app navigates to `/oauth` which triggers the oauth flow. the authorization server then redirects the client to `/oauth2callback`. I am trying it out locally and the first step works fine. The server is able to redirect the client to google's authorization server and receive the `code` that is meant to be exchanged for an access token. However, when I try to exchange the `code` using `flow.step2_exchange` the http requests hangs for a very long time. Usually the request times out. Occasionally I do get a response back with a valid access token, which leads me to believe that the logic is (generally speaking) sound.

Does anybody know what might be causing google to delay the response for 30 seconds or more? Could it be that google is throttling development requests? Has anyone encountered something like this before? Is there something I am doing wrong? I should note that I am currently using google own oauth2 library but I've tried constructing the http requests manually and that didn't help either. It still hangs on `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token`.

This is the flask code for the oauth flow:

```
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow

@app.route('/oauth', methods=['GET'])
def oauth():
    print "oauth called: "
    flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
        client_id=config.GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret=config.GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
        scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
        redirect_uri='http://localhost:6060/oauth2callback')
    auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
    return redirect(auth_uri)


@app.route('/oauth2callback', methods=["GET"])
def oauth_callback():
    code = request.args['code']
    flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
        client_id=config.GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret=config.GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
        scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
        redirect_uri='http://localhost:6060/oauth2callback')
    credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
```

Comment: I suspect a DNS issue. Could it have something to do with your server's IP stack being IPv6 enabled but the routing/out-going-firewalling isn't in place?

Comment: I'm trying it out on locally on a macbook pro. I don't have any special firewall restrictions in place so it doesn't seem likely. also when I run "dig accounts.google.com" I get back an IPv4 address: 216.58.192.45

Comment: Check for a browser window that appears with a google page asking you to (login and) grant the permissions.

Comment: it was IPv6 after all. Trying it from a location other than my office it worked fine. if you write it up as an answer I'll mark it as correct